# Endpoint, Spring Security Configuration returning: The method cannot decide whether the patterns are Spring MVC or not

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-framework-beans, security-filter

SecurityFilterChain beans in SecurityConfiguration returning this error I doesn't found anything about this method that solved it:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration {
        
          @Bean
            public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
                return  httpSecurity
                        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/login").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/register").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/product").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        )
                        .build();
            }
    }
```

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method
> 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot
> decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this
> endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use
> requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use
> requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This method cannot
> decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this
> endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use
> requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use
> requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

Comment: Are you sure about the `login` and `register` endpoints on a resource server ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cause is described here [cve-2023-34035](https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035)

And also some discussions about this topic, you can find here [13568](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13568)

As a workaround you can do something like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
        .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/test1")).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );
    return http.build();
}
```

**UPDATE** **TO 24.10.2023**

About the fix and how to deal with this for future i suggest to check next one [details(issuecomment-1759913041)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13568#issuecomment-1759913041)  from Development Team of Spring Security