# Springboot keycloak oauth2 bean dependency errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, bean-validation

So i am trying to use Springboot and keycloak authorization and authentication for a simple login form. Am getting this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'clientFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/login/java/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Factory method 'clientFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/login/java/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'clientFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'clientFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

The errors are shortened to only required lines.
KeyCloak is running on 8080 with realm master

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.login.java.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;

@Configuration  
@EnableWebSecurity  
class SecurityConfig{   
    
    @Autowired
    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;  
    
    @Autowired
    SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {   
        this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler; 
    }
    
    @Bean
    SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() { 
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());    
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain clientFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/"));    
        return http.build();        
    }


    @Order(2)
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/home*")
                .hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated());  
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt); 
        return http.build();    
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {   
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class) 
            .build();   
    }   
}
```

**LoginController.java**

```
package com.login.java;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.login.java.model.user;
import com.login.java.model.userInterface;

@Controller
public class LoginController
{
    String lol = "LOL";
    private userInterface userInterface;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Autowired
     public LoginController(userInterface userInterface) 
     {
        this.userInterface = userInterface;
     }

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String checkMVC()
    {
        return "login";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/login")
    public String loginHomepage(
            @RequestParam("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            Model model)
    {
        user u;
        System.out.println("Searching for user: " + username);
        u = userInterface.findByUsername(username);
        if (u != null)
        {
            System.out.println("User found: " + u.getUsername());
            model.addAttribute("username", username);
            return "home";
        }

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/register")
    public String gotoregisterationpage()
    {
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/create-user")
    public String gotoregistermicroservice(
            @RequestParam("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            @RequestParam("cpassword") String cpassword,
            Model model)
    {
        if (password.equals(cpassword))
        {
            // Construct URL with path variables
            String registrationUrl = "http://localhost:8081/register-user/"+username+"/"+password+"/"+email;

            // Create UriComponentsBuilder to build the URL with variables
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(registrationUrl);

            // Set path variables
            builder.queryParam("id", 1)
            .queryParam("username", username)
                   .queryParam("password", password)
                   .queryParam("email", email);

            // Make a GET request using RestTemplate
            restTemplate.getForObject(builder.toUriString(), String.class);

            model.addAttribute("registrationSuccess", "Registered Kindly Login!!");
        }
        else
        {
            model.addAttribute("registrationError", "Password Not matching!!");
            return "login";
        }

        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/logout")
    public String logout()
    {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.login</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>skam-login</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
        <oauth.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</oauth.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${oauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**
Application.properties**

```
##DB Connection
spring.datasource.url= #has correct URL
spring.datasource.username = #has correct username
spring.datasource.password = #has correct pass
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.open-in-view= false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

##MVC view
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**

server.port = 8081

##Spring Security
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration

##KeyCloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/master
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/master
```

**My Folder tree structure**

```
│   .classpath
│   .gitignore
│   .project
│   HELP.md
│   mvnw
│   mvnw.cmd
│   pom.xml
│   README.md
│
├───.settings
│       org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
│       org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs
│       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
│       org.springframework.ide.eclipse.prefs
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───login
│   │   │           └───java
│   │   │               │   LoginController.java
│   │   │               │   SkamLoginmApplication.java
│   │   │               │
│   │   │               ├───config
│   │   │               │       KeycloakLogoutHandler.java
│   │   │               │       RestClientConfiguration.java
│   │   │               │       SecurityConfig.java
│   │   │               │
│   │   │               └───model
│   │   │                       user.java
│   │   │                       userInterface.java
│   │   │
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   │       application.properties
│   │   │
│   │   └───webapp
│   │       └───WEB-INF
│   │               home.jsp
│   │               login.jsp
│   │               register.jsp
│   │
│   └───test
│       ├───java
│       └───resources
└───target
    │   microservice-0.0.1.jar
    │   microservice-0.0.1.jar.original
    │
    ├───classes
    │   │   application.properties
    │   │
    │   ├───com
    │   │   └───login
    │   │       └───java
    │   │           │   LoginController.class
    │   │           │   SkamLoginmApplication.class
    │   │           │
    │   │           ├───config
    │   │           │       KeycloakLogoutHandler.class
    │   │           │       RestClientConfiguration.class
    │   │           │       SecurityConfig.class
    │   │           │
    │   │           └───model
    │   │                   user.class
    │   │                   userInterface.class
    │   │
    │   ├───META-INF
    │   │   │   MANIFEST.MF
    │   │   │
    │   │   └───maven
    │   │       └───com.login
    │   │           └───microservice
    │   │                   pom.properties
    │   │                   pom.xml
    │   │
    │   └───WEB-INF
    │           home.jsp
    │           login.jsp
    │           register.jsp
    │
    ├───generated-sources
    │   └───annotations
    ├───generated-test-sources
    │   └───test-annotations
    ├───maven-archiver
    │       pom.properties
    │
    ├───maven-status
    │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
    │       ├───compile
    │       │   └───default-compile
    │       │           createdFiles.lst
    │       │           inputFiles.lst
    │       │
    │       └───testCompile
    │           └───default-testCompile
    │                   createdFiles.lst
    │                   inputFiles.lst
    │
    └───test-classes
```

Tried to see the migration documentation of spring security 6 and spring cloud but just couldn't find the solution.

Adapters are decapitated so went on to use spring security resource server and was faced with this error of Bean.

Even if this goes some others comes up like antmatching.

Comment: based on error trace check the answer of this question that i gave [The method cannot decide whether the patterns are Spring MVC or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852537/endpoint-spring-security-configuration-returning-the-method-cannot-decide-whet/76865442#76865442)

Comment: Thank you for this will keep in mind about the builder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to the problem you report is given by Andrei Lisa in his answer. You should upvote the answer he links.

However, there are quite a few other mistakes in the config you report:

- you have no `securityMatcher` in the filter-chain with highest priority (the client one) => it will intercept all requests and the resource server filter-chain will never get a chance to be tried.
- access to `/login/**` and `/oauth2/**` should be processed by your client filter-chain and be listed in the `permitAll` routes if you want login to work
- you have configured nothing to convert Keycloak roles to Spring authorities. This not done the same way for clients and resource server.
- Keycloak is fully compliant with OIDC. You should be using Spring Security logout **sucess** handler for OIDC instead of defining your own logout handler (`LogoutHandler` and `LogoutSuccessHandler` are not the same thing).

If using ["my" starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#oidc-starter), you'd have no Java conf at all and avoided the problem you report as well as all those I listed.

Comment: downvoted becuase recommending to use an unknow starter that is not supported by spring, and become dependent on a single developers own private project. I dont encourage this and i dont recommend anyone to use that as there are no guarantees that the project will live for any specific time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm convinced it is a good thing for readers to know why an answer might not be pertinent. I'm not asking you to revise your vote, but please note that the core  of the answer (almost 90%) is about configuration issues in the question, not about my starter. Also, maybe should you take some time to have look at what this Spring Boot starter does and, more importantly, how it does it and how you could fork it if was to take a direction you don't like: it is open-source and even if not supported by Spring saved me a lot of time writing (and maintaining) many apps.

Comment: even thou an answer is 90% about something its still 10% that should not be there, i still dont think pushing the general public to use some unknown project is secure, its more bad practice to use unknown 3rd party dependencies. The world already has enough problems with 3rd party dependencies, and the starter has nothing to do with the answer more than self promotion. Its one thing pushing people to own blogposts, tutorials as long as the information is correct. But unknown code, with unknown guarantees. No.

Comment: So many valuable open-source projects started just like that. And also, unless you don't test access rules in your OAuth2 apps, you already are using some code originated from the lib you want to prevent others to use: it served as an incubator for OAuth2 `MockMvc` request post-processors and `WebTestClient` mutators that I contributed to `spring-security-test`. But again I'm fine with the fact that you can expose your opinion with down-votes, especially when it comes with a comment so that any reader can understand the motivation and value of this vote.

Comment: And by the way, referencing my starter here has more value than self promotion: out of the box, **It solves the problem in the title plus all those that I list**. Yes, it really does, with just properties. Just try.

Comment: Downvote still stands, i gave my reason (which i actually dont even need to) have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for the mistakes you found in securityConfig time to read some more documentation.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that "my" tutorials I link in "my" repo **start with detailed instructions on how to configure Spring apps with only "offical" starters**. "My" starter is introduced as a 2nd step to ease conf.  So even if you agree with @Toerktumlare about 3rd party libs, you'll find useful instructions there.