# Sprint Security and H2-Console: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am facing a problem when trying to use the H2 console in my application. Every time I try to run the application, a specific error appears, and I am looking for assistance in understanding and resolving this issue. The error I am facing is the following. Can you help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it? I am open to any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
2023-10-26T00:42:58.601-03:00  WARN 7320 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/liferay/CommunityApp/configs/security/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
```

and this is my SecurityConfiguration class code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    SecurityFilter securityFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/new-post").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer about few weeks ago, you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852537/endpoint-spring-security-configuration-returning-the-method-cannot-decide-whet/76865442#76865442)