# Configuring security in Spring boot 3.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-resource-server

I'm migrating from Spring boot 2.5 to 3.1 and I'm having issues getting the security configuration working.

This is my current configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig {

    private static final String[] WHITELISTED_ENDPOINTS = {
        "/docs",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/v2/**", "/v3/**",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/css/corner-ribbon.css",
        "/actuator/**",
        "/api/health",
        "/camunda-welcome/**",
        "/camunda/**",
        "/api/engine/**",
        "/api/admin/**",
        "/api/cockpit/**",
        "/app/**",
        "/lib/**",
        "/api/tasklist/**"
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(WHITELISTED_ENDPOINTS)
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .build();
    }

}
```

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in some.org.security.ResourceServerConfig: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

> This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer=[/camunda/api/admin/*], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

I'm assuming the issue is here:
The main server is tomcat but the application has jersey config for Camunda rest engine

```java
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/engine-rest")
public class CustomCamundaJerseyResourceConfig extends CamundaJerseyResourceConfig {
    protected void registerCamundaRestResources() {
        super.registerCamundaRestResources();
    }
}
```

It was working on spring boot 2.5, any idea how to get it working on 3.1?

Comment: Hi ! I wrote an answer related to your problem some time ago, just check this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852537/endpoint-spring-security-configuration-returning-the-method-cannot-decide-whet/76865442#76865442)